# Using forms in main form's panel with any size in Visual Studio

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

I'm working on VB.NET tool. Attached there's a basic scheme of my question. I'd like to use secondary windows forms in my primary(main) form's defined panel area. Secondary forms will contain toolstrip and menustrip also i would like to use them in my main form with best responsive way.

Do you suggest any elements to use for second form or first form like (flowlayoutpanel, toolstripcontainer, etc.)

[image: scheme of my question]

For adding the other forms in my first form's panel area there should be a code like that but i don't very well because it didn't worked on me.

```
  Dim f As New Forms
    f.TopLevel = False
    f.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized
    f.FormBorderStyle = Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.None
    pnlMainPanel.Controls.Add(f)
  End Sub
```

Note: I'm using Visual Studio 2012, .NET Framework 4.5.2 OS: Windows:7, VB.NET

Comment: Why not just use the MDI functionality that is built into Windows Forms?

Comment: @jmcilhinney MDI doesn't provide me flexibility i have also own toolstrip and sidebar control on main menu. I want to make design look like one-piece/monoblock.

Comment: That's pretty much a non-answer but then why use a form instead of a user control?

Comment: @jmcilhinney i don't know user control very well and in fact i didn't use it before but i checked on internet for usage of it but i didn't understand very well it's usage field for my case. I'll have several 3-4 different secondary(child) form with their own toolbar also on secondary form. I'll select the mode from main (parent) form and child form will change according to my mode selection.

Comment: A user control is designed just like a form but then used just like a control. It seems to be pretty much exactly what you need in this case. You should look into the subject.

Comment: @jmcilhinney thanks for your helps. I'll search on net. Also do you know a content similar to my case could you please share with me ? I guess searching with wrong keywords :)

Comment: You should be able to simply use the `Dock` properties of your controls to achieve the desired layout.  You might need to experiment a bit with z-order but I believe that if you add the top `Panel` first and set `Dock` to `Top`, then add the bottom `Panel` and `Dock` it to `Bottom`, then add the left `Panel` and dock to `Left`, then you can just add your user control(s) as required and set their `Dock` property to `Fill`.  If your z-order isn't correct already then you can adjust it in the Document Outline window.

Comment: @jmcilhinney In fact i designed my form. `Dock` Panel of Sidebar to `Left`, `Dock` Panel of Navigation to `Top`, `Dock` Panel of  Footer(Statusbar etc.) to `Bottom`. Finally for my working area Main Panel `Dock` to 'Fill' for remaining space. I think we have same approach is it true? Now you are offering me to put user control as child form to filled panel (Main panel). Did i understand correct ?

Comment: That's pretty much it, but the there's no point to that last `Panel`.  It serves no useful purpose.  Just put the user control there on the form itself, rather than putting the `Panel` on the form and the user control on the `Panel`.

Comment: @jmcilhinney In that case how can i call designed user control form from my main gui

Comment: It's a control. It's the same as any other control. Stop asking me to teach you the basics and go and do some research.

Comment: There is just a minor mistake in the snippet, you have to set the form's Visible property to True yourself.  Maximizing the form has no effect, set the Dock property instead.